# Select range in a particular sheet in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, select, range

I have a question about selecting a range in a particular sheet using excel vba.

I don't know why the following is not working:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("N&A").Range("B4:F16").select
```

However this works:

```
Thisworkbook.Sheets("N&A").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("B4:F16").Select
```

The VBA code is programmed on "N&A" sheet.

Could anyone let me know what could be the reason?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question. Here's an excerpt from [Excel 2003 help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221576%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

"If you use the Select method to select cells, be aware that Select works only on the active worksheet. If you run your Sub procedure from the module, the Select method will fail unless your procedure activates the worksheet before using the Select method on a range of cells."

More importantly, remember that it's rarely necessary to use `Select` in VBA, and it should be [avoided if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select).

Comment: Thank you! I saw Macro recorder was using range.select, that's why I had it here. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score -1):

You can try with following code to aviod acriveworksheet:

```
Sub Clean()


lastrow = Worksheets("REPORT").Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Report")
Set rng = ws.Cells(1, 1)
With ws
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastrow, 5))
End With

rng.Clear

End Sub
```