# Excel VBA - How to select colums in a specific sheet?

Tags: excel, vba, select

I need to select columns on a specific sheet. Somehow this is not working:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Mysheet")
ws.Columns("A:S").Select
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

And simple `Columns("A:S").Select`doesn't activate the sheet I need

Comment: Possible duplicate of other topics like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559677/select-range-in-a-particular-sheet-in-excel-vba). While I understand it can be difficult to formulate and search for a problem on Google, please have some attempt to look at possible previous answers.

Answer (score 4):

I tested your code and it works fine as follows.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Mysheet")
    ws.Columns("A:S").EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

No need to `Select` anything, so I put the two statements together without the `Select`.

I added `ThisWorkbook` to (more) fully qualify your `ws` declaration. Make sure the worksheet `Mysheet` is in `ThisWorkbook` otherwise change that to state which workbook the sheet resides in.